# How to Deploy WCF Class Library Project on My Domain Name

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, wcf, deployment

I've created a **wcf class library project** which connects to a sql server 2008 database and does some work and I want to publish this service, so that all our clients can have access to it, by their apps. 
Anyway, what I've got with the deployment process so far :

1- publishing my sql server 2008 files done, everything's ok.

2- publishing Wcf service library - well , somehow ok ! :)

I've been studying about the different options for deploying a WCF Service and since my clients are using an android app to connect to my REST service ( json output), I think I'd need to host my service inside IIS, (or otherwise I'm wrong)

The real problem is that, we've purchased a host space and domain name from a provider, on which the server's os is WinServer 2003 and also the administration panel for the host is Website Panel. but it supports .NET 4.0 and other stuff.

**I've worked hard on this, but I couldn't get the service working on that host space, by uploading the .svc and other files.
My questions are :**

**1- how can I deploy my service on such a server successfully, using the Website Panel ?**

**2- how can I configure the service , so that I can access it by my domain name ?**

I'm on a tight deadline , so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think thats possible. You need access to the server's IIS, thats where WCF services are getting deployed.

Comment: Hi @Pantelis, what do you recommend? should we buy a VPS or sth ?

Comment: Yes, you will need a dedicated server.

Comment: actually I don't want to get involved with the whole server configuration process like DNS ( moving my domain to the server) and security configs. Is there any way around this ?

Comment: You can leave your websites at your current host but you will need access to a dedicated server's IIS, or Windows Azure in order to host WCF services.

Comment: can't we create an ASP.NET web application that only runs the service, or sth like this ? if you give me just some keywords, I'll go search for it.

Comment: You can't. ASP.NET websites/applications and WCF Services are both hosted on IIS. You could create a self-host WCF service (hosting options would be any managed application WindowsService, WinForms, WPF) but this still requires access to the Windows Server OS which you don't have. Plus you will get the overhead of controling the lifetime of your service manually, a job that IIS does for you. 

Check the hosting options for WCF here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729846(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: You're right. We do need access to the IIS, directly. Thank you very much.

Comment: No worries. Don't forget to mark an answer if one solves your problem.